# Is there a way of putting the facebook social plugins into page template php files?

Tags: facebook, php, templates

I was wondering if there was any way of putting the features that come with the "Facebook" wordpress plugin, such as comments, recommend and subscribe, on my front page which I created using a template page, like maybe a do_shortcode or get_shortcode solution to put it into the page?

Thanks :)

Comment: You are self-hosting the blog or is it hosted by wordpress.com?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Facebook developers site

For example, the Like Plugin
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Generate the code.  You'll get the generated code back in 2 blocks.  The first is the SDK that must be added once on your page... preferably after the opening `<body>` tag.  Depending on your theme you can paste that directly into header.php.  If you have a child theme you might do it with hooks and filters... I can't say.

Then Facebook says to place the second part of your code wherever you'd like it to appear, so in your case directly in your page template.  You might even be able get away with pasting both sections of code directly into your page template.

There are a lot of plugins in the plugin repository that deal with Facebook if you aren't comfortable with code.

Answer (score 0):

@Cleaus

You can do it using Facebook plugin developed by Facebook team, you can download it from wordpress plugin directory as well as from Facebook, check below links...

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/

http://developers.facebook.com/wordpress/

This plugins having features like...

- Like, send, and subscribe buttons can be enabled in a click and are fully customizable.
- Facebook Comments, including full SEO support.
- Mention friends and Facebook Pages. This posts to their Timelines as well as lists them on the WordPress Post or Page.
- Post all new WordPress Post or Pages to a specified Facebook Page.
- Post to an Author's Facebook Timeline whenever they publish a new WordPress Post or Page.
- Recommendations bar, which allows users to click to start getting recommendations, Like content, and add what they're reading to Timeline as they go.
- Facebook Open Graph Protocol integration.

More details are also available in [Screenshot](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/screenshots/) Tab of WP Plugin Page and Facebook link also.